# Passing value to Cobol program through Parm using data in sequential file

Tags: cobol, jcl

I am setting up a JCL which will pass value of date coming from a sequential file (has one record) (example 20190320) to parm as shown below:

//STEP1 EXEC PGM=ABC,PARM='20190320'

I am trying to pass value of PARM with value of date containing inside sequential file.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your COBOL program already contain instructions to retrieve the information passed from JCL using `PARM`, you may use the `PARMDD` parameter in conjunction with a DD statement to achieve the task. The DD statement is to define the sequential file with `PARM` data.

```
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=ABC,PARMDD=MYINPUT
//MYINPUT  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=MY.PARM.INPUT
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
```

Dataset `MY.PARM.INPUT` can have the value of date.

Basically, you can't pass more than 100 bytes of data using PARM parameter. `PARMDD` is usually preferred if you want to pass data > 100 bytes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this in the one job.
Options include

- Changing the program **ABC** to read from the file
- Writing a program/rexx to read the file and call the program **ABC**
- Read the file and **Generate** a new job that calls **ABC** with the date you have just read. This could be done in a rexx script.
- Some scheduling systems might support this.

Please provide a bit more information

- What scheduling system does your company use
- Is the program ABC a locally written program ??? that can be changed
- Is the job part of a batch stream run automatically or submitted by a user.

---

### Manual Submission

If the job is being submitted manually you could

- Write a Rexx Script using [ISPF file tailoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.f54dg00/ispdg197.htm) to generate && submit the JCL
- Rexx Macro to update and submit the JCL

#### ISPF Edit macro

you could have

```
// set DATE=$Date$ 
//STEP1 EXEC PGM=ABC,PARM='&date'
```

in the jour JCL
and have the [rexx edit macro](http://theamericanprogrammer.com/programming/holymac.shtml)

- read the file
- do a replace all on &date
- I would use the same variables as Controlm

With JCL

```
// set DATE=$Date$ 
//STEP1 EXEC PGM=ABC,PARM='&date'
```

the edit macro would some thing like

```
   /* rexx */
  ADDRESS ISREDIT 'macro'
  Address TSO "EXECIO 1 DISKR indd"
  pull date
  ADDRESS ISREDIT "r $date$" date 
  ADDRESS ISREDIT "cancel"
```

The *edit macro* needs to be in the SYSPROC or SYSEXEC libraries. If the 
Macro is called **ChgDate** you would just

Comment: I don't want to make change in Cobol program ABC. Job is submitted manually in test. I am not planning to schedule it in production. (In production the value is coming through Control-M variables). My aim is to reduce my burden to pass symbolic parameter values manually, when running in test.

Comment: I’d write a REXX script that reads in the file and builds the JCL for the COBOL program or dynamically allocate all the required DDs and invoke it.